# images are not fading properly

Tags: html, css

I have written this html code to print one image over another using fading animation, but in the output image is printed before the previous image vanish completely, so please tell what is the problem in my code?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Interactive Alphabet Learning</title>

  <style>

   #crossfade > img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 156s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 156s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 156s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 156s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 156s linear infinite 0s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 36s;
    -o-animation-delay: 36s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 36s;
    animation-delay: 36s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 42s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 42s;
    -o-animation-delay: 42s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 42s;
    animation-delay: 42s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(9) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 48s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 48s;
    -o-animation-delay: 48s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 48s;
    animation-delay: 48s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(10) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 54s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 54s;
    -o-animation-delay: 54s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 54s;
    animation-delay: 54s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(11) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 60s;
    -o-animation-delay: 60s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 60s;
    animation-delay: 60s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(12) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 66s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 66s;
    -o-animation-delay: 66s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 66s;
    animation-delay: 66s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(13) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 72s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 72s;
    -o-animation-delay: 72s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 72s;
    animation-delay: 72s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(14) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 78s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 78s;
    -o-animation-delay: 78s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 78s;
    animation-delay: 78s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(15) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 84s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 84s;
    -o-animation-delay: 84s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 84s;
    animation-delay: 84s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(16) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 90s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 90s;
    -o-animation-delay: 90s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 90s;
    animation-delay: 90s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(17) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 96s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 96s;
    -o-animation-delay: 96s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 96s;
    animation-delay: 96s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(18) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 102s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 102s;
    -o-animation-delay: 102s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 102s;
    animation-delay: 102s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(19) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 108s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 108s;
    -o-animation-delay: 108s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 108s;
    animation-delay: 108s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(20) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 114s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 114s;
    -o-animation-delay: 114s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 114s;
    animation-delay: 114s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(21) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 120s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 120s;
    -o-animation-delay: 120s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 120s;
    animation-delay: 120s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(22) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 126s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 126s;
    -o-animation-delay: 126s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 126s;
    animation-delay: 126s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(23) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 132s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 132s;
    -o-animation-delay: 132s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 132s;
    animation-delay: 132s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(24) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 138s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 138s;
    -o-animation-delay: 138s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 138s;
    animation-delay: 138s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(25) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 144s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 144s;
    -o-animation-delay: 144s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 144s;
    animation-delay: 144s; 
   }

   #crossfade > img:nth-child(26) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 150s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 150s;
    -o-animation-delay: 150s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 150s;
    animation-delay: 150s; 
   }

   @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
   }

   @-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
   }

   @-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
   }

   @-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
   }

   @keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
         animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
   }


  </style>
 </head>

 <body style="background-color:yellow">
  <h1 style="color:black; text-align:center; font-family:Comic Sans MS">Interactive Alphabet Learning</h1>
  <hr style="border-color:#E30B5D">

  <div id="crossfade">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) 0 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -300px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -600px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -900px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -1200px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -1500px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -1800px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -2100px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -2400px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -2700px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -3000px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -3300px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -3600px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -3900px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -4200px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -4500px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -4800px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -5100px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -5400px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -5700px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -6000px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -6300px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -6600px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -6900px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -7200px 0;" alt="Image 1">
   <img style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: url(download.jpg) -7500px 0;" alt="Image 1">

  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe it'll work if you specify the file in the `src` parameter, and not in the style:
`src="download.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, you want the current image to fade out completely before the next image starts fading in.

The problem with the CSS is that the keyframes are done so that the fading occurs from 0% to 25% of the animation length which is 156s as specified at the top. This means the animation occurs over 39 seconds (25% of 156s), instead of 6 seconds.

If you are set with cycling over 26 images, try using the following percentages instead:

```
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
         animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    1.282% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    2.564% { opacity: 1 }
    3.846% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

These values are based off the calculation 6/156 = 3.846%.